# TSP solution interpretation

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, octave, genetic-algorithm

> This is mostly a consulting question.

I've developed a genetic algorithm to solve the [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), long story short, I have written two different codes the and i used [this](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/zi929.tsp) as my dataset. the programs' found solution are shown below.

[image: prog#1 solution]

[image: prog#2 solution]

As it is obvious the suggested solution from the first program(**`Prog# 1`**) is much more promising than the second one(**`Prog# 2`**) to be optimized; and the solution from `Prog# 2` seems to be a random solution most likely.

**BUT** the cost of `Prog# 1` as i have calculated is **`97314.36`** and the cost of `Prog# 2` is **`74635.31`** which is almost **20K smaller** than the cost of solution from `Prog# 1`, and as costs are suggesting the solution found by `Prog# 2` **SHOULD BE** much more optimized than the first solution.

## Question

1) Why on earth the path plot of solution found by `Prog# 2` does not support (visually) the calculated cost value?

2) Considering the blow scripts, is there anything i have missed?

---

For completeness i post the script i used to plot and calculating the cost value.

```
function tsp_plot_output() 
    close all;
    disp('loading data....');
    x=load('out.res'); 
    dist = 0;
    for i=1:2:size(x, 1)-1
        dist = dist + norm(x(i,:) - x(i+1,:), 2);
    end
    dist = dist + norm(x(1,:) - x(end,:), 2);
    fprintf('COST IS: %.2f\n', dist);
    disp('ploting data....');
    xx = x(:,1); xy = x(1:size(xx, 1),2);
    zxx = x(:,1); zxy = x(1:size(zxx),2);
    plot(xx, xy), title('Found TSP solution');
    hold
    plot(zxx, zxy, 'r.');
end
```

The code i used in `Prog# 1` to pour out the solution is

```
std::ofstream os(outputfile);
BOOST_FOREACH(size_t city, *best->_genes) {
    auto loc = _data->get(city);
    os<<loc.longitude<<" "<<loc.latitude<<endl;
}
os.close();
```

And same code in `Prog# 2`

```
ofstream out(jconfig["output-file"].as_string());
for(int i = 0; i < p->lchrom; i++) {
    city c = data.at(best_found->chrom[i]);
    out<<c.x<<" "<<c.y<<endl;
}
out.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by you have calculated. Which are you sure of: the visualization, or the cost, or neither.

Comment: Cost simply is just sum of point-to-point euclidean distance, but there should be some reasonable relation between visualization and cost. which I don't see that in `Prog# 2 `'s visualization.

Comment: Also I don't think this is a very good question because the answer to 1) is: because there is a bug in either visualization or plotter. And the codes you show are 2x c++ snippets for printing data which do not tell anything beyond that they output two columns of data (there can be tons of problems, but I doubt there are any if output look resonable and program doesn't crash), and one unspecified script for plotting. You tagged it `c++` and c++ codes you show absolutely do not help in solving your issue. So it is very hard to tell if you missed something.

Comment: I use matlab/octave to plot, so i don't think there is a bug in their plot :)
and beyond the snippet  `C++` code i have send is just genetic algorithm which has nothing to do with the outputting the result

Comment: I figured what is the meaning of cost. It is also obvious there should be a relation. But you said *you* calculated the value. I highly doubt you calculated ~100 distances. You have bug either in distance calculation or visualization/plotting. What makes you think there is a relation for Prog#1, maybe it should be 50k? I doubt there is a bug in their plot. From what plotting and distance calculation is done in `tsp_plot_output`. My bet is you have bug there. If it's octave, maybe you should ask question with `octave` tag whether your script does what you think it does. I'm not good enough =)

Comment: You could also try smaller cases which you can check by hand, of course. Cheers and good luck =).

Comment: Of course i calculated ~1000 distances, for 10000 solution for 2000 times :D that is the point of genetic algorithm.
The same cost function i used to calculate the distance in `Prog# 1` i used in `Prog# 2` and is being used in the `tsp_plot_output` script, and the cost results are match with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distance calculation im MATLAB is wrong. You have:

```
dist = 0;
for i=1:2:size(x, 1)-1
    dist = dist + norm(x(i,:) - x(i+1,:), 2);
end
dist = dist + norm(x(1,:) - x(end,:), 2);
```

With `for i=1:2:size(x,1)-1` you start at `i=1`, and then add `2` in each step until you reach `size(x,1)-1`. Therefore, you add the distances from `1-2`, then from `3-4`, and so on. Of course it should be from `1-2`, then `2-3` and so on. This is achieved by

```
dist = 0;
for k=1:size(x,1)-1
    dist = dist + norm(x(k+1,:) - x(k,:),2);
end
dist = dist + norm(x(end,:) - x(1,:),2);
```

For an example `x = [0,0; 1,1; 1,0]` the old routine returned `2.4142`, while the corrected one returns the correct `sqrt(2) + 1 + 1 = 3.4142`.

PS: I changed the running variable to `k`, as in MATLAB `i` stands for the imaginary unit (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) for details). 
I also changed the order of the `x`'s inside the `norm`. Of course yours wasn't wrong, but that way it is clear that you take the vector from the current point `k` to the next point `k+1` and not the  other direction.

Comment: +1 you are right!! wonder how i came to this obvious mistake!
I am running my program again with my cost function fixed,  it would take an hour or two to complete, I'll get back to you about the result.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, the new result confirms that, cheers:)